# Undefined constant CURLINFO_SCHEME using PHP 7.3.8

Tags: php, curl

I need to test if HTTPS is available for a URL using PHP, but `CURLINFO_SCHEME` is returning an `Undefined constant` error. I'm using the latest PHP version, so I'm baffled as to what the problem is.

```php
php -V  
PHP 7.3.8 (cli) (built: Jul 30 2019 09:26:16) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.8, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.8, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.7.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2019, by Derick Rethans
```

PHP Curl version

```php
var_dump($version = curl_version());
array (size=14)
  'version_number' => int 475137
  'age' => int 4
  'features' => int 4162461
  'ssl_version_number' => int 0
  'version' => string '7.64.1' (length=6)
  'host' => string 'x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' (length=23)
  'ssl_version' => string 'NSS/3.36' (length=8)
  'libz_version' => string '1.2.7' (length=5)
  'protocols' => 
    array (size=22)
      0 => string 'dict' (length=4)
      ...
  'ares' => string '' (length=0)
  'ares_num' => int 0
  'libidn' => string '' (length=0)
  'iconv_ver_num' => int 0
  'libssh_version' => string 'libssh2/1.8.2' (length=13)
```

I'm running on CentOS 7.6 server.

Here's the curl command which produces the issue.

```
$domain = 'example.com';

$domain = rtrim(preg_replace('/^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?/', '', $domain), '/');

echo $domain . "\n";

$domain = "https://" . $domain;

function curl_check_ssl($domain) {

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array( $curl, array(
CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.109 Safari/537.36',
CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
CURLOPT_NOBODY => true,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_VERBOSE => false,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'HEAD',
CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 2,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 4,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE => CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4,
CURLOPT_URL => $domain
    ) );
curl_exec( $curl );

$curl_scheme = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_SCHEME);
// $curl_scheme = curl_getinfo($curl);
curl_close( $curl );

return $curl_scheme;

}

var_dump(curl_check_ssl($domain)) . "\n";
```

Comment: `CURLINFO_SCHEME` doesn't appear on the docs for `curl_getinfo`, so I guess it hasn't been implemented?

Comment: According to PHP docs it's been available since 7.3.0 https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.constants.php#constant.curlinfo-scheme

Comment: Good spot, you're right. Just tested on PHP 7.3.7 Curl 7.61.0, and it works as expected. Is the error you're getting via the CLI (just to check))

Comment: No I'm running the code in the browser.

Comment: What command did you run in the terminal to test?

Comment: Then it's possible your webserver is running an older version of PHP. Add `var_dump(phpversion())` to the code you're calling in your browser and see what you get.

Comment: I ran `$ch = curl_init('http://facebook.com'); curl_exec($ch); var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_SCHEME));`

Comment: The PHP version returns `7.3.8`. This is bizarre.

Comment: Check the curl version via the browser too just to be sure.

Comment: If I run `var_dump(curl_version());` in the browser it returns `  'version' => string '7.64.1' (length=6)`

Comment: No idea then I'm afraid.

Comment: Running your code in the terminal returns the same message `PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant CURLINFO_SCHEME - assumed 'CURLINFO_SCHEME' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in php shell code on line 1
`. Thnaks for your help anyway.

Comment: @Jonnix, Just wondering, how did you install Curl on your system? Are you using RHEL/Centos? I installed Curl using the city-fan.org repo, and think it can't have been compiled with the latest Curl options like `CURLINFO_SCHEME`.

Comment: Ubuntu, via `apt` from the `ondrej` php repos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

When installing PHP it will usually compile against the installed version of Curl. Because I installed PHP with the Yum package manager it looks as though PHP compiles against the latest version of Curl contained in Yum which right now is Curl 7.29. This version does not support `CURLINFO_SCHEME`. So, although I have the latest version of Curl installed on my system, PHP through Yum ignores this version.

You can check the various PHP constants compiled into the extension with:

```
$ strings /usr/lib64/php/modules/curl.so | grep CURLINFO | sort
```

If the result does not contain `CURLINFO_SCHEME`, to get PHP to recognize this constant I believe the only way is to install PHP from source.

If like me, you don't want to install PHP from source then you can use the numerical value for `CURLINFO_SCHEME` instead e.g `1048625`.

Just replace the constant with it's numerical value:
`$curl_scheme = curl_getinfo($curl, 1048625);`.

[Curl constant numericals](https://github.com/lightbend/reactive-cli/blob/master/cli/native/src/main/scala/com/lightbend/rp/reactivecli/http/nativebinding/libcurl.scala)